# How to start process from standard user without providing admin credentials in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to start process from standard user without providing admin credentials. I am writing code in C#. I read some of the answers from internet but no one is working.

Here is my sample code:

```
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = "EXEPath";
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "argument";
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                proc.Start();
                proc.Close();
```

I am writing this code but still it can asking for admin credentials while I am running my windows application. Please help me! TIA!

Comment: Is your user allowed access the exe's path? Is your application, running the code above, startet with or without elevated rights?

Comment: One more problem is that you are starting a process with `proc.Start()` and closing it immediately after start with `proc.Close()`. You may try to remove `proc.Close()` and check

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine no admin credentials ased and notepad++ is opened

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SO
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "newfile.txt";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No difference to the question in your code. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @nilsK: The differences should be trivial, in that we assume that the OP used comparable arguments, but having a full sample may help the OP and future readers understand how to properly reference the executable, while reaffirming that admin credentials _shouldn't_ be needed. Of course, I assume the real issue may lie with the permissions of e.g., `newfile.txt`.

Comment: @JeremyCaney good points, thanks for your feed back